# Convergence of sequence of random variables almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

Assume $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3,...$ are independent and identically distributed R.V.s s.t. $Z_n∈(-1,1)$. Prove the following:

1) $Z_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. almost surely.

2) $Z_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. in $L_1$.

I think i should start with the definition of almost sure convergence and fix an event w and observe the sequence $Z_1(w), Z_2(w), Z_3(w),...$, but what event should i fix on? and for L1, since its L1, we have to prove the expectation of $Z_n $converges to 0 but I dont think it is uniform distribution so how would i approach that?

Comment: Do you want to prove that the two statements are equivalent ?

Comment: prove each seperately i suppose i dont have any thoughts for the second one; ill add that sorry

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct witout any addition assumption. For example if the distribution is $\delta_{\frac12}$, then $Z_n = \frac12 \not\rightarrow 0$

Comment: the question states that $P(|Z_i|<1)=1$ i thought Zi was a typo so I just typed out that |Zn|<1; i think these two statements are equivelent?

Comment: Yes the two statements are equivalent can you give the source of the question ?

Comment: it is a question I found on my midterm practice I do not have the source unforteunately...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75716/discussion-between-youem-and-james-black).

Answer (score 2):

Both are false. Obvious counter-example $Z_n=\frac 1 2$ for all $n$. Independent sequences rarely converge.